# RobustRankAggreg R package: multiple testing

Tags: r

I'm using the `AggregateRanks` function of the RobustRankAggreg R package. Does anyone know if the returned Scores (p values) are already corrected for multiple testing, or if I should correct for multiple testing myself? The documentation did not say whether they were already corrected or not.

Comment: I was going to suggest you reach out to the original author, but since the package hasn't been updated in over 8 years and an [issue](https://github.com/raivokolde/RobustRankAggreg/issues/1) asking if it is maintained has gone unanswered ... doesn't look promising.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [RRA paper](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/28/4/573/213339), I assume returned scores have to be adjusted because of the following part:

> As a minimum of P-values, ρ score itself is not a P-value. Hence, it
> must be corrected against bias coming from multiple hypothesis testing
> to determine statistical significance.

Speaking of how **exactly** it should be done:

> ... we can use Bonferroni correction for each ρ score separately to
> find an upper bound on the associated P-value. For that we must
> multiply each ρ score with the number of input lists.

And then:

> After the correction, we can decide whether the ranking of a
> particular gene is statistically significant. To find all significant
> genes, we have to correct derived (estimates of) P-values further for
> multiple testing. This can be done we with standard methods.

So what I did eventually is:

```
ranks_result <- as.data.table(aggregateRanks(glist = glist))
ranks_result[,rra_score_adj:=rra_score*length(glist)]
ranks_result[,rra_score_adj:=p.adjust(rra_score_adj, method="BH")]
ranks_result[rra_score_adj<=0.05] # to see what is significant
```

You can replace `method="BH"` with another method you would prefer in your case. I will be happy if anyone can give any suggestions here!